# libgdx optimal Height and Width

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Does it matter what height and width I use for my game? In my game I have a few polygons, they all are connected to images that I have painted, but when I have width and height as 800x480 I have to paint the images very small, this causes them to get blurry. Also, I don't really understand how this behaves on different sized phone screens.., does the images I have painted get streched, or do they stay small, even on big tablets? So my question is basically what is the optimal width and height to have on a libgdx game?

This is a part of my code, to maybe help you understand what I mean

```
    WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480 );
```

What will happen if I change these values? What would it be best to change them to?

I was reading on a tutorial of sorts, but they didn't really talk about this part.

Do I have to do something complicated to get my painted images to look decent on all devices?

EDIT:

This is how I currently implement a cloud into my game:

```
public class AnotherScreen implements Screen{

Polygon cloudPoly;
Texture cloud;

    @Override
public void render(float delta) {

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    renderBackground();
    batch.draw(cloud,cloudPoly.getX(),cloudPoly.getY());
    batch.end();

    }

    @Override
public void show() {
    cloud = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/textures/cloud.png"));
            cloudPoly = new Polygon();
    cloudPoly.setPosition(MathUtils.random(350,600),MathUtils.random(380,440));

    // theses vertices are just a little square atm
    float[] cloudVertices = new float[] {
            0,0,
            0,20,
            20,20,
            20,0
    };
    cloudPoly.setVertices(cloudVertices);
    }
```

}

The cloud image has width 256p and height 128p, when I set 'camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480 );' won't this cloud always stay in proportion?

I am sorry if I am unclear, I am a new programmer and my english could be better, love you doh for staying with me!

Comment: Consider naming your units. 800x480 what? meters? inches? Which units fits best for your game?

Comment: `getWidth` and `getHeight` give you the screen size in pixels. Setting the camera's width and height sets up the viewable area of your world, but the units can be anything you like, like Xoppa said. If you're using box2D, then meters is a good choice. The 800x480 you set will be stretched to fit the screen, no matter the size and aspect ratio of the device. So if you just choose fixed values like this, it will look distorted on some devices. Look at the libgdx documentation on Viewports, which handles this issue.

Comment: hmm okey, so.. I should not use fixed values for it to look good on all devices? I will take a read on viewports, but, is there a way you could show me an example on how to not use fixed values? If I make an image in photoshop that's 32x32 pixels, how do I implement that image the right way? Right now I just import it and if the size is wrong I change it in photoshop, seems like that's wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **does the images I have painted get streched, or do they stay small, even on big tablets?**

One of the greatest features of libgdx is that it lets you do things exactly as you want them. So, it is really your choice. With this snippet

```
WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

You would have a different viewport size in every different screen size. So your images would stay small.

In the other hand, if you use predefined values for the viewport like:

```
WIDTH = 800;
HEIGHT = 480;

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

You would get the same viewport for every screen and the images would stretch to occupy the same space in each axis. This won't necessarily be the same for each axis. So a perfect square image in one screen may look like a rectangle in another screen with a different x-y ratio.

There is a third option, you can fix one side and let the other be calculated, so you keep the ratio of your images (a square stays as square). You must decide what will be the fixed side. For a game like [Super Mario Bros](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-svLuEXnT6zM/UjXCAaWVUtI/AAAAAAAAIXg/2O2t0mxeCEQ/s1600/mariobros.png) I would recommend you to fix the height and calculate the width:

```
HEIGHT = 480;
WIDTH = (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/Gdx.graphics.getHeight())*HEIGHT;

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Every screen would see the same height in the game world. But some screens would see more in the width than others. If thats a problem for you (you want them to see the same ammount of the world but keep the ratio too), than adding black bars to each side is an option.

> **So my question is basically what is the optimal width and height to have on a libgdx game?**

The optimal solution is having a different set of images for several resolutions. And choosing whats the most appropiate at runtime. But that increases the game size a lot.

Another dirty way is having only one big set and let the images shrink in lower resolutions. It looks better than the inverse. But some people think this is just too dirty :p (not me, so I recommend it).

Comment: but what you said about 'a different viewport size in every different screen size', that sounds pretty good, doesn't that mean all pictures will look the same on all screeens, or is it just the opposite maybe?

Comment: It means the opposite.

Comment: When i created a game i used to choose the size with meters in my head. If i want to be able to see about 80m in x and 45m in y, i created a `camera` with a viewport of 80 and 45. Then i created the objects, again with meters in my head (a human f.e. had a size of 2 in y as it is about 2m tall). Is this the wrong way in your oppinion?

Comment: Nop, it is a good way. (Actually the second option I posted in the answer).

Comment: @Lestat thanks! When i started learning libgdx a tutorial showed me, that thats one of the best ways, but i almost never see someone doing it like this. Even with box2d, instead of using this approach, they use metersToPixel and pixelsToMeter. This was a bit confusing for me xD

Comment: I am not using box2d, my problem is that I can't really explain I guess, but can you take a look at the edit I made and see how you would have done it?

Comment: @Springrbua yeah I also find annoying people use pixeltometers when there is no need to. And I blame the first adopters of libgdx who made tutorials and everyone followed up u.u

Comment: @Lestat Do you have a good size for scaling down? Say if you were making a fullscreen background. Currently mine is 960x1600 and it looks good on my phone (Galaxy Nexus 5), but dont have naything else to test on.